# Using javax.xml.xpath. with scala.xml

Tags: xml, scala

Is it possible to use `javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression`s with `scala.xml.NodeSeq`s?

I'd like an API that allows me to express something like:

```
val xml = ...
val xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance.newXPath.compile(
    """/this/that/theOther[@abc="123"]""")
val selectedNodes: NodeSeq = xml.applyXpath(xpath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it an absolute requirement that its Scala XML and javax.xml.xpath?  Or that you'd rather use string based XPaths within Scala.

[Scales Xml](http://code.google.com/p/scala-scales) has added string based XPath usage (as well as the faster internal syntax) but I haven't yet decided if it makes sense to provide a javax.xml.xpath implementation.

If this is something useful for people I'd consider spending more time on implementing it.

Comment: Yes the latter. I only wanted to use xpaths with Scala. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Scala takes a functional approach to searching through XML. In same cases it's not as clear as XPath and takes some getting used to it. For example:

```
scala> val myXml = <books><book category="1">first</book><book category="2">second</book><book category="1">third</book></books>
myXml: scala.xml.Elem = <books><book category="1">first</book><book category="2">second</book><book category="1">third</book></books>

scala> (myXml \ "book").filter { node => (node \\ "@category").text == "1" }
res24: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<book category="1">first</book>, <book category="1">third</book>)
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, that does not address the question:  Is there an existing library that mixes `javax.xml.xpath` with `scala.xml`

Comment: You also had the second question: "Is there an alternative?". I answered the second one.

Comment: The answer to my revised question (because I didn't really care about the alternative) is "No, it is not possible". But have a tick anyway. :)